Verilog HDL quicksort Error: must use only constant expressions in terminating conditions
I'm trying to run this Verilog code in Quartus II, but because of for it doesn't work.
module verilog_qs(
    input  wire clk,
    input  wire [10:0] in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, in6, in7, in8, in9, in10,
    output reg  [10:0] out1, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8, out9, out10
);

    reg signed [10:1] data [0:10]; 

    function automatic integer partition;
    input integer l, h;
    integer pivot;
    integer left_wall;
    integer i;
    integer temp;
    begin
        pivot = data[h];
        left_wall = l - 1;
        for (i = l; i < h; i = i + 1)
        begin
            if (data[i] < pivot)
            begin
                left_wall = left_wall + 1;
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[left_wall];
                data[left_wall] = temp;
            end
        end
        temp = data[h];
        data[h] = data[left_wall + 1];
        data[left_wall + 1] = temp;
        partition = left_wall + 1;
    end
endfunction


    function automatic integer qs;
        input integer low, high;
        integer pivot;
        integer stack[0:10]; // Stack to store indices
        integer top;
        integer part_index;
        integer ignored;
        begin
            top = 0;
            stack[top] = low;
            top = top + 1;
            stack[top] = high;

            while (top >= 0)
            begin
                high = stack[top];
                top = top - 1;
                low = stack[top];
                top = top - 1;

                if (low < high)
                begin
                    part_index = partition(low, high);
                    top = top + 1;
                    stack[top] = low;
                    top = top + 1;
                    stack[top] = part_index - 1;
                    top = top + 1;
                    stack[top] = part_index + 1;
                    top = top + 1;
                    stack[top] = high;
                end
            end
            qs = 0;
        end
    endfunction

    integer ignored;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        data[1] = in1;
        data[2] = in2;
        data[3] = in3;
        data[4] = in4;
        data[5] = in5;
        data[6] = in6;
        data[7] = in7;
        data[8] = in8;
        data[9] = in9;
        data[10] = in10;
        ignored = qs(1, 10);
        out1 = data[1];
        out2 = data[2];
        out3 = data[3];
        out4 = data[4];
        out5 = data[5];
        out6 = data[6];
        out7 = data[7];
        out8 = data[8];
        out9 = data[9];
        out10 = data[10];
    end

endmodule

I tried using a while loop, but that didn't work.

This error occurs when a function is being called recursively in the code and the compiler (in this case the RTL tool) has to unroll the entire recursive call but it is unable to build a forward propagating netlist out of it. Now there are two reasons for this error:

Either due to some issue in the code, the recursive call will never ends, such as (for example), if this condition low < high keeps evaluating to true than the recursive call will never end.
Or the recursive call ends but not with in some specific number of iterations. Each tool has its own specific value to unroll a function/loop up to a specific depth. For example Vivado has 2000 iterations. So if this number exceeds than the tool will give this error.

You have two ways either try to increase the number of iterations if you believe your recursive will eventually converge or identify the mistake that is causing the infinite recursion.
FYI: I am getting this error in vivado for this code:
ERROR: [Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations

